# How to schedule a daily sql script in snowflake db

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema, snowflake-task, snowsql

How to schedule a sql script in the snowflake database to run every day, and set the output file name to include the current date. E.g. if the code ran today then the file name should be `20200906*****.csv.gz`, similary for tomorrow `20200907******.csv.gz`.

Answer (score 4):

You could use Snowflake **TASKS** in order to schedule execution of SQL statements.
Task can execute a single SQL statement, including a call to a stored procedure.
Tasks run according to a specified execution configuration, using any combination of a set interval and/or a flexible schedule using a subset of familiar cron utility syntax.

For your goal I would create a Stored Procedure (so that you could use variables for managing changing filename and for any more complex things).

SF Doc: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-task.html

```
--create a new task that executes a single SQL statement based on CRON definition
CREATE TASK mytask_hour
  WAREHOUSE = mywh
  SCHEDULE = 'USING CRON 0 9-17 * * SUN America/Los_Angeles'
  TIMESTAMP_INPUT_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24'
AS
INSERT INTO mytable(ts) VALUES(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);


--create a new task that executes a Stored Procedure every hour
create task my_copy_task
  warehouse = mywh
  schedule = '60 minute'
as
  call my_unload_sp();
```

After creating a task, you must execute *ALTER TASK … RESUME* in order to enable it.

Use *SHOW TASKS* to check your task's definition/configuration and then query *TASK_HISTORY* in order to check executions.

Your Snowflake JS Stored Procedure could be something like this:

```
create or replace procedure SP_TASK_EXPORT()
    RETURNS VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL
    LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
    EXECUTE AS CALLER
as $$    

function getToday_yyyymmdd()
{
    var v_out_Today;
    rs = snowflake.execute ( { sqlText: `SELECT to_char(current_date,'yyyymmdd');` }  );
    if( rs.next())
    {
       v_out_Today = rs.getColumnValue(1); // get current date as yyyymmdd
    }

    return v_out_Today; 
}   

  var result = new String('Successfully Executed');
  var v_Today = getToday_yyyymmdd();

  try {
       
    var sql_command = `copy into @unload_gcs/LH_TBL_FIRST` + v_Today + `.csv.gz from ........`;
 
    var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: sql_command});
    var res = stmt.execute();
     
    
   }
    catch (err) {
    result =  "Failed: Code: " + err.code + " | State: " + err.state;
    result += "\n  Message: " + err.message;
    result += "\nStack Trace:\n" + err.stackTraceTxt; 

  } 

 return result;

  $$;
```

Before creating your task and schedule it, test your Stored Procedure invoking it:

call  SP_TASK_EXPORT();

Comment: Could you please tell me how to include date in file name as I mentioned in my question. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share your SQL script in order to understand how it works. Thanks

Comment: Please find the below script. In the 20200902 place, I want date in the same format daily  . For ex if script runs today, then file name will be LH_TBL_FIRST20200906.                                                                                                           copy into @unload_gcs/LH_TBL_FIRST20200902.csv.gz from 
(
select 
*

from TEST_BASE.LH_TBL_FIRST
)
file_format = (
  type=csv compression='gzip' 
  FIELD_DELIMITER = ',' 
  field_optionally_enclosed_by='"' 
  NULL_IF=()
  EMPTY_FIELD_AS_NULL = FALSE 
)
single = false
max_file_size=5300000000 
header = false;

Comment: See an example inside my answer